# how make my xml simpler

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

Using vb.net aspx

First My Webservice function return a Datatable ... but the xml returned describe it as a NewDataset and each row is a table instead of a row. And have some additional info like `<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">`

Because this webservice is for smartphone i want the xml be the smaller possible to save kb from data plan.
So i want xml doesn't include the additional info  ... a simple `<row> </row>` should be enough

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function CityTraffic2(x1 As Double, y1 As Double) As DataTable
...
'4. Populate the DataSet
Dim myDataSet As New DataSet
da.Fill(myDataSet)
Return myDataSet.Tables(0)
```

Comment: You'll be better off, in the long run, if you stop using datatables and use strongly-typed objects.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question... didnt know you could highlight text in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in a similar situation was define my own class that can be mapped to a data-row and then just return an array of that class.  That way not only does the web service not have to pass all the extra metadata, but you have some extra abstraction in case you change your data layer

Comment: Thanks, that solve my problem. Sorry i cant vote because dont have 15 rep.

Comment: Look at that ... i got additional rep ... i guess someone pass and help me with those +5 rep ... in that case Thank you !! :)